# Did I use realloc in a wrong way?

Tags: c, linux, memory, realloc

This is a part of my program which is related to realloc(). I give the array `myEdge` an initial size `my_edge_num`, when this size is not enough, realloc() more space to it. However, even though the new realloc `temp_edge` is not NULL, it still says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the next step when it reaches the location in the array which beyonds old size but less than new size.

```
string_first = strtok_r(buffer, " \t\n", &save_ptr);
int i=0;

int temp_edge_num;
Edge *temp_edge;
while (string_first != NULL)
 {
    temp_first = atoi(string_first);

    string_second = strtok_r(NULL," \t\n",&save_ptr);

    temp_second = atoi(string_second);



    if(i>=my_edge_num)// if it finds that it reaches original size
    {
        temp_edge_num = i + EDGE_NUM_ADJUST;//add more size

        temp_edge = (Edge *)realloc(myEdge, temp_edge_num);//allocate more space
        if(temp_edge)// if allocate more space successfully 
        {
            myEdge = temp_edge;// let original = new one
        }
        my_edge_num = temp_edge_num;

    }

    if((p_id[temp_first]==partitionID)||(p_id[temp_second]==partitionID))
    {
        myEdge[i].first=temp_first; //it says EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
        myEdge[i].second=temp_second;
    }



    i++;



    string_first = strtok_r(NULL, " \t\n", &save_ptr);

}
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor English...... It should be "Did I use realloc in a wrong way".....

Comment: If realloc fails then you pretend that you have enough space when in fact you don't

Comment: regarding this line: 'string_second = strtok_r(NULL," \t\n",&save_ptr);'  always check the returned value from strtok() before using it.  if this call to  strtok() returns NULL, then this line: 'temp_second = atoi(string_second);' will cause a seg fault event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reallocate too few bytes.

It should be

```
temp_edge = realloc(myEdge, temp_edge_num*sizeof(Edge));//allocate more space
```

instead.

Comment: @ammoQ , Yes. You [should not cast the result of `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` in C](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)